# Drawer menu blocked by fragment menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

So, I have an app that are using drawer menu and some fragments. But, when the fragment i'am on a fragment that have a menu, it completely blocked my drawer menu even if the burger icon is still visible.

[image: Fragment with menu]

But, when i press the back button and exit current Fragment with its own menu, the drawer menu works again. It seems like the menu from fragment are blocking the drawer menu. Here is my code for adding menu provider into fragment :

```
val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(
        this,
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
    )
```

And here is my code for inflating the menu :

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
    val myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.btn_search_menu)
    val searchView = myActionMenuItem.actionView as SearchView?
    searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            (context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager)
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(view?.windowToken, 0)

            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean = false
    })
```

Comment: Have you found answer to this? After trying to use addMenuProvider the drawer used by `AppBarConfiguration` stop working.

Comment: haha i actually have solved it long ago, but thanks anyway. i'll mark ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the right answer, you need to return `false` in `onMenuItemSelected` if you want the `AppBarConfiguration` to take care of the navigation click again. It is the way of saying that we are now passing the handling of menu's click event back to the Jetpack Component.

```
    activity?.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {

        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            // Do your inflation here
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            R.id.action -> {
               // Do your stuff here
               return true // Click event is now your responsibility
            }
            else -> false // Click event responsibility back to Android
        }

    })
```

In your Activity nothing will change, you still need to override `onSupportNavigateUp` like this

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```